# How to change spinner state via String dynamically?

Tags: android, android-spinner

Suppose I have spinner loaded with values.Gujarat,Maharashtra,UttarPradesh,Bihar,now when I run this activity then by default Gujarat selected,now I have one String data which contains all this states displayed above and it will initialize dynamically at run time,now I want is spinner must set the value that is available in String data at run time not default value like Gujarat.

Comment: You'll want to find the index of the value that should be selected in the `Spinner`'s backing dataset and call [`setSelection(int)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsSpinner.html#setSelection%28int%29).

Comment: no i dont want to go via index .Is there any method that change state of spinner via given value by user??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't test this, but it should work, so try this code:

```
Spinner mSpinner = YOUR_SPINNER;
    String elementToFind="";
    int index = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i<mSpinner.getCount(); i++){
        String myString = (String) mSpinner.getItemAtPosition(i);
        if(myString.equals(elementToFind)){
            index = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    mSpinner.setSelection(index);
```